# Auto-link functions to the manual?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I thought it would be nice if "left alone" functions were "auto-linked" to the appropriate page on the language's manual. For instance, if a user back-ticks ("left alone") a PHP function like: `array_filter`, have it auto-link to the PHP manual like so: [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

It doesn't seem too difficult to impliment, seeing as it's a simple injection into a URL's manual:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.***array-filter***.php

I think it's very annoying when you are answering a question and you have to search up functions in the manual. Additionally, it's annoying to see an answer with a function that doesn't have a link. Call me lazy, but I think it would be a nice feature to the site.

Example:
    [How to convert an array of arrays or objects to an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563119/array-map-callback-access-to-associative-array-key-and-value).

I see this all the time, answers with functions that don't have a link to the manual. I think it would definitely benefit users.

This is ***NOT*** a duplicate of: [Auto Manual Link Suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26142/auto-manual-link-suggestion?rq=1), which suggests to link entire questions to the manual.

Comment: How would the system know if this is supposed to be a PHP function?

Comment: I don't think anyone would use the word "array_filter" with backticks when speaking normally. There are only a limited number of functions out there. Also, it would need a "PHP" tag, which would make tags mean more.

Comment: downvote for a suggestion??

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: Thanks for the link Bolt. I think most answers have a manual link, so I think it would be really useful, it would be used for almost 50% of the posts.

Comment: I assume you would use the question tags to determine which language?  And if so, how would you handle something tagged with multiple languages that have the same class name (like List<T> in C# and Java)

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't get it, why would you tag multiple languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117372/documentation-links-in-markdown

Comment: @JohnSmith: [tag:PHP], [tag:JavaScript]

Comment: @JohnSmith It happens fairly often.  Perhaps because they don't care which language they get a solution for, perhaps because both are applicable, or perhaps both are involved in the solution in some way.

Comment: @Servy So forever new tab, google, copy link, paste?

Comment: And then there are the hordes of users who `backtick` absolutely `everything` that shouldn't `even be` in code backticks.

Comment: @JohnSmith When you need to link to documentation yeah.  I tend to not do it all that often.  The reader can do the google search if they want to find more info in most cases, so I won't bother to link every single class/method I reference in a post/comment.

Comment: @J.Steen I `don't` know `what` you're `talking` about. :P

Comment: This would be a job for an external entity that provides and maintains a "linking engine" in the format `domain.com/language/functionname`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this script on Stack Apps: [Editor buttons for injecting documentation links](https://stackapps.com/questions/2234/editor-buttons-for-injecting-documentation-links)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: +1 I'm giving best answer here.

Answer (score 10):

Just getting it to work would be a nightmare.

First you'd need to ensure the question had the appropriate tag, then you'd need to come up with the single canonical site for documentation for that tag (note some tags wouldn't have a single canonical source), then you need a way of generating that function's doc page given that documentation site, (Note not all language will be simple text insertion as with your example; MSDN doesn't use the class/function name in the url for the docs.) then you need to resolve issues with multiple tags, say a question with both `C` and `C++` or `PHP` and `JavaScript`, etc.

Comment: I digress then.